# Why does the Spring form:hidden tag print two value attributes?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Basic question, but haven't found any other relevant posts on SO.

I have this Spring code in my JSP with a property called `vacant`:

`<form:hidden path="vacant" value="false"/>`

And here is the generated output:

`<input id="vacant" name="vacant" value="false" type="hidden" value=""/>`

Why would `value` get printed twice with an empty second one?

(It's relevant because I'm trying to use the `value` in some Javascript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is "normal". According to the doc:

> This tag renders an HTML 'input' tag with type 'hidden' using the
>   bound value

Let's assume vacant is `Boolean vacant;` in your DTO, since its value is null, the tag'll print it as `value=""`. In addition, it'll print any other field you pass to it, e.g:

```
<form:hidden path="vacant" my-field="test"/>
<input id="vacant" name="vacant" my-field="test" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

So if you happen to use value in `<form:hidden path="vacant" my-field="test" value="true"/>`, it'll consider it an additional field:

```
<input id="vacant" name="vacant" my-field="test" value="false" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Here is what happens in the source:

**org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag**

```
protected int writeTagContent(TagWriter tagWriter) throws JspException {
    ...
    writeDefaultAttributes(tagWriter); // *) Here it'll print the value that you passed to the tag
    ...
    //The next two statements get the bound value of vacant (null) and print it as value=""
    String value = getDisplayString(getBoundValue(), getPropertyEditor());
    tagWriter.writeAttribute("value", processFieldValue(getName(), value, "hidden"));
```

*) writeDefaultAttributes() calls writeOptionalAttributes(), where your passed value is printed (it's in this.dynamicAttributes along with my-field):

```
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.dynamicAttributes)) {
    for (String attr : this.dynamicAttributes.keySet()) {
        tagWriter.writeOptionalAttributeValue(attr, getDisplayString(this.dynamicAttributes.get(attr)));
    }
}
```

So, http:input is intended to be used for bound values, so set the value you need in the DTO before rendering the JSP.